# Error in view - 'float' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, django

I am getting error in my view during template rendering

> 'float' object has no attribute 'label'

It has to do with this line I just added a float conversion

```
 form.fields['quantity_order'] = float(bom.quantity) * float(quantity)
```

(I added float since I was  getting different problem > "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Decimal'")

```
 @login_required
    def Production_order_new(request, pk_bom, pk_soproduct, uri, quantity):
        uri = _get_redirect_url(request, uri)
        bom = get_object_or_404(BOM, pk=pk_bom)
        soproduct = get_object_or_404(SOproduct, pk=pk_soproduct)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = Production_orderForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                Production_order= form.save(commit=False)
                #contact.author = request.user
                Production_order.creation_time = timezone.now()
                Production_order.material = bom.material
                #Production_order.quantity_order = bom.quantity * quantity
                Production_order.SOproduct = soproduct 
                POmaterial.save()      
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,  "-SUCCESS Object created sucssefully")
                return redirect(uri)
        else:
            form = Production_orderForm()

            form.fields['quantity_order'] = float(bom.quantity) * float(quantity)
            #form.fields['Vendor_AM'].queryset = Vendor_AM.objects.filter(company=company)
        material = bom.material
        return render(request, 'production/productionorder_edit.html', {'form': form, 'material':material })
```

This is my basic form

```
class Production_orderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Production_order
        fields = ['quantity_order','production_notes', 'agent', 'is_picked']
```

This is how my quantity field defined in model

```
quantity_order = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=3)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You've assigned a float as a field. Why?

Comment: The problem is that you are assigning a float to what should be a form field object.

Comment: You probably want to do that in the `__init__` method of the form and use `self.fields['quantity_order'].initial = ...` to assign the value

Comment: I try to pre -  populate the field in form with this calculated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer what worked for me

```
data_dict = { 'quantity_order': float(bom.quantity) * float(quantity)}

form = Production_orderForm(data_dict)
```